# Handling Lists of complex objects in Javascript/JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts

This is my server side class

```
public class DefinitionT implements java.io.Serializable {

private int id;
private String value;
    .....
```

the two fields have getters and setters.
On my JSP side I have a var declared as

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var g_definitions="<s:property value="definitions"/>";
</script>
```

My Struts Action has a getter called getDefinitions which gets called and returns a list of DefinitionT objects.
In my JS I have the following code

```
    for( var i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) 
{ 
    $("#definitionsDiv").append(g_definitions[i].value);
}
```

Firstly I was trying to figure out how to get the number of objects in the list but 
g_definitions.size   is "Undefined"
If I try to access g_definitions[0].value it is also undefined.
How do I handle this list properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign a java list directly to a javascript variable.

You have two options
Convert the java list to json object.
Use jstl or snippets to get the value from the variable

```
<s:iterator value="definitions" var="defination">
       $("#definitionsDiv").append(<s:property value="defination"/>);
</s:iterator>
```